# Listing million+ records in Android with multiple list ui items

Tags: android, performance, layout, android-listview, android-sqlite

In one of our app, we have to list around a million+ records that are stored in an internal sqlite database and show them in a list view separated by multiple list view UI layouts.

For example, the list will look like :

```
Area 1   
    Location A  
        Person 1  
        Person 2  
        Person 3   
    Location B   
        Person 4  
        Person 5
Area 2   
    Location C  
        Person 6  
        Person 7  
        Person 8   
    Location D   
        Person 9  
        Person 10
```

and so on...

Now, the Areas are in hundreds, the Locations are in thousands in number and Persons are in millions. Area, Location & Person are models (tables) with multiple attributes attached to them. I've to use 3 different list item layout for Area, Location & Person records.

I've used [Endless Adapter from CWAC](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) with custom BaseAdapter in my implementation. I'm fetching and storing the Areas & Locations in ArrayList and I've delegated the fetching of Person records to Endless Adapter. It is working as expected but as the number of records for Person(s) keep growing (which is normal in the app), the list view generation is getting slow day-by-day. Other than that there are filters that come into play to filter the area, location & persons. So for each filter the query for fetching the area, the location as well as the person changes. And we also have Search feature in the app where the user can search for a particular area, location or a person and the list view refreshes the data accordingly.

I'm not allowed to show the actual records and source code which would have helped in understanding the complex data in a better way, Sorry!

Is there any *better* way to do this and improve the user experience and save user's time? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

@[Squonk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488241/squonk) - The users can actually edit the records of Persons at any given point in time like changing their location, names, birthdate, etc. The users can also change the Location that they want to pursue. For example, a user can store New York & London for his/her preference even if the app has multiple other Locations for him/her to choose. Once the user selects the Location he/she will be able to see the Persons available on those Locations.

@[tophyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518159/tophyr) - The EndlessAdapter helps me to fetch 30 records at a time for a given Area & Location which I keep it in memory for display. Once the user scrolls and last record is reached, the EndlessAdapter refreshes and my data in the memory refreshes too. As soon as there are no Person records left, I alter the query to get the next Location and the EndlessAdapter starts fetching the Person records based on the new query.

@[CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) - Yes, the millions records are not stored in device's RAM but they have to be searched, filtered and shown to the user and for this, I use your awesome library. I may be guilty of implementing it in the wrong way and that's why I seek help in improving it.

Comment: What you've omitted from your description is explaining what any user of your app will actually want from your data source at any given time that they use it. Do they really want access to all areas or all locations or all people? Why do they want to access your data? For what purpose?

Comment: How does the BaseAdapter work? Are you growing a list of Persons infinitely in memory or are you making a database query for each row as it's loaded? Or some hybrid? How about the database itself - is the Person table indexed for fast lookups? It's very hard to suggest optimizations without knowing implementation details. Try to abstract the project into a sample that repros the problem but doesn't give away anything actually confidential.

Comment: "we have to list around a million+ records that are stored in an internal sqlite database and show them in a list view separated by multiple list view UI layouts" -- nobody is going to scroll through "a million+" rows in a `ListView`. You don't even have *RAM* for "a million+" rows.